# What is the image position of the object $AB$ by a lens?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometric-optics

> On the spherical silver surface of a glass lens $\left(n = 1.5\right)$ with radius $10 \, \mathrm{cm}$, a ray of light penetrate the plane surface of the lens, and then **reflected** on the silver surface to be **refracted** again by the face plane.
>
> 1. Determine the position and the height of the image by the system of the objects $AB$ which is located $5 \, \mathrm{cm}$ from the $C$, as shown in the figure.
> 2. What would be the equivalent of this system?

[image]

---

1. I can't use the spherical mirror formula since the spherical surface is inside the glass which has an incidence coefficient $n$, unlike the case of the spherical mirror where $n_{\text{air}}=1$. How can I determine the position $\bar{SA'}$
2. For This question, the equivalent system would be a lens with the same focal values, which I can determine when I will have the correct formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try traditional ray-tracing to find the answer to (1).

(Be careful, because I don't think that drawing is to scale with the numbers given; the radius doesn't look to be twice the C-A distance)

- A ray from B to C will bend by a calculable amount, then travel on the mirror where it will hit perpendicular and come straight back along the same ray. So your image of B will be somewhere along that line.
- A ray parallel to the axis will hit the glass perpendicular and therefore continue straight.  It then hits the mirror at a calculable angle to the normal, and reflects back by that same angle on the other side of the normal, proceeding to the surface of the glass and out. The image of B is also along this line.

With a sketch, it looks like those two will intersect inside the glass and below the axis, so that's your image.

To find an equivalent lens, think about finding an "effective center":  the point on the axis where light emerging at any angle will be reflected back to the same point.  The focus is twice as far away.  (But think clearly about how rays bend as they cross the glass interface; this is a bit of a trick question)

Comment: What would be the center $C$ and the point $S$ of an equivalent mirror?